# using . opearator inside backticks javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So this is a bit of an unusual situation i am in but what i need to do is access the value of an object based on what index its stored in. The problem is that i need it in my `Select` component of material ui. So the overview is that i store alginment values of a video . the videos show up in a loop which means the select values are repeated and to know if its for the first video i append the index inside the object like this:

[image: Object]

Now in order to set the option i have to access this value here :
[image]

Now the problem is in this loop i cant do something like :
`halign.halign[index]` because obviously that would mean its an array. So long story short how could i do something like :

`` value={`${halign.halign}${index}`} ``
So basically the end result for value to evaluate is : `halign.halign0`
and so on for each index. 
NOTE the outer halign is the main useState object.

Comment: `halign[\`halign${index}\`]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that for JavaScript objects `x['y']` and `x.y` are interchangeable.

So if you need to compute the key you're looking up, use:

```
halign['halign' + index]
```

Or template strings if you prefer.

Note this would be a lot easier if you organized your object with an internal array, so you could just do `halign[index]`.

Comment: Yes this worked thank you! I'll accept in a bit its not allowing me right now lol. also can you give me like a reference to what you said above about x[y] and x.y being same thing for objects i didn't know that yet. Thank you.

Comment: This is covered in [JavaScript 101](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), so be sure to check out the MDN introduction to it.

Comment: `x['y']` and `x.y` are interchangeable, but `x[y]` would imply that `y` is an identifier which could be any value, which is not the same as `x.y`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Good point, updated accordingly.

Comment: @EmileBergeron yes I understood that. Thank you for your help guys.