# How can i concatenate using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Here method is dynamic based on user input method value will be change

```
var method = 'GetActiveUserData';
```

How can i concatenate  ? please help below expected output added

```
var result =  data["s:En"]["s:Body"][0].`${method}`Response[0].`${method}`Result[0]["a:datas"][0]["b:data"];
```

Expected output:

```
data["s:En"]["s:Body"][0].GetActiveUserDataResponse[0].GetActiveUserDataResult[0]["a:datas"][0]["b:data"];
```

Comment: `+` is string concatenation in javascript

Comment: Look into this question it may have your answer :
[Javascript dot operator inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531767/using-opearator-inside-backticks-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[]` on objects to access properties based on an expression:

```
var result = data
  ["s:En"]
  ["s:Body"][0]
  [`${method}Response`][0]
  [`${method}Result`][0]
  ["a:datas"][0]
  ["b:data"];
```

`obj['blah']` is logically equivalent to `obj.blah`, so if `method` is `GetActiveUserData`, `` obj[`${method}Response`] `` is equivalent to `obj.GetActiveUserDataResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Template string is available in most browser

```js
var result =  `data["s:En"]["s:Body"][0].${method}Response[0].${method}Result[0]["a:datas"][0]["b:data"]`;
```

But if it doesn't work, you may try a simple string concatenate:

```js
var result =  'data["s:En"]["s:Body"][0].' + method + 'Response[0].' + method + 'Result[0]["a:datas"][0]["b:data"]';
```

Comment: var rawAllocations = ata["s:En"]["s:Body"][0].${method}Response[0].${method}Result[0]["a:datas"][0]["b:data"];
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Template string should be available in most browser but if it doesn't work, you may use a simple javascript string concatenate. I'll update my answer